# append html content to html using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have html code like this :

```
<td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sun fc-past" data-date="2016-07-17"></td>
<td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-past" data-date="2016-07-18"></td>
```

I want to append html if the data-date come's in between startdate and enddate.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var d = $(".fc-day").data('date');
    $.ajax({
        url : '<?php echo base_url()."admin/utilities/get_task_assign_staff" ?>',
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(responce){               
            $(".fc-day").each(function(){
                var d = $(".fc-day").data('date');
                if(d == responce[0].startdate)
                {
                    this.append("<span class='fc-title'>"+responce[0].name+"</span>");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

For Example, my startdate is `2016-07-05` and enddate is `2016-07-09` than append `responce[0].name` to the given `<td>` that data-date come's in between startdate and enddate.

So what jQuery should I have to write?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url : '<?php echo base_url()."admin/utilities/get_task_assign_staff" ?>',
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(responce){      
        $('.fc-day').each(function(){
            var data_date = $(this).attr('data-date'),
               response = $.parseJSON(responce);
            if(data_date == response.startdate){
                $(this).html("<span class='fc-title'>"+response.name+"</span>");
            }
        });
      }
   });
});
```

1. You want to get the attribute date_date from the elements that contain the class fc-day. This is how you get this attribute.

   $('.fc-day').each(function(){var data_date = $(this).attr('data-date');});
2. You have indicated that you expecting JSON as response, so you want to probably use parseJSON for the responce you got.

I hope i helped to solve your issue. Cheers